# How to order JSON data received from API by foreign key ID

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to order data received from an API according to a foreign key ID of another table. In this case, ordering a bunch of symptoms by their corresponding symptom type.

In the Symptom.ts file:

```
export class SymptomsPage {
  symptoms: any;
  symptomtypes: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataProvider: DataProvider) {
    this.getSymptoms();
    this.getSymptomTypes();
  }
  getSymptoms() {
    this.dataProvider.getSymptom()
    .then(data => {
    this.symptoms = data;
    console.log(this.symptoms);
    });
    }
  getSymptomTypes() {
    this.dataProvider.getSymptomType()
    .then(data => {
    this.symptomtypes = data;
    console.log(this.symptomtypes);
    });
    }
}
```

In the symptoms.html file:

```
<h1>Symptoms</h1>
<h2> {{symptomtypes[0].Description}}</h2>
<ion-item *ngFor="let symptom of symptoms">
    <ul>
        <li *ngIf="symptom.SymptomTypeID === 1">
            <p> {{symptom.Description}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ion-item>
```

Which is basically hard coded and inefficient. 
 

 I expect the result to be the following handling for the case of new symptoms and types being added later: 
 **Symptom Type 1**  
Symptom of type 1 
Symptom of type 1 
 
 **Symptom Type 2**  
Symptom of type 2 
Symptom of type 2 
 **Symptom Type 3**  
Symptom of type 3 
Symptom of type 3 
 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to add foreach in ts file(if only one field) like

```
 this.symptomstype.forEach((symtypeItem) => { // foreach statement 
        this.symptoms.forEach((symItem) => {
            if(symItem.type == symtypeItem.type)  {
               //add values to array
             }
          })

    })
```

Use this array in view(html file).